# Issues with Trigger on insert (t-sql)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers, insert

Say I have a self relation table as following :

```
   ID - Name - ParentID
```

Now everytime that users insert sth in this table I would like to check if the Name inserted is already in the 
rows where `ParentID` equals to the inserted one , if true then rollback the transaction.

But the problem is when I check the rows with the `parentID` from the inserted table the inserted row is already in the main table too. So, the trigger always rolls back the transaction.

Here is my trigger :

```
ALTER TRIGGER TG_Check_Existance_In_myTbl
ON myTbl FOR INSERT,UPDATE AS


DEClARE @result BIT
DECLARE @numberOfRows INT
DECLARE @counter INT
DECLARE @names nVARCHAR (30)
DECLARE @name NVARCHAR (30)
SET @result = 0
SET @numberOfRows = (SELECT COUNT (Name)
                    FROM myTbl
                    WHERE ParentID IN
                        (
                            SELECT ParentID
                            FROM inserted
                        )
                    )
SET @counter = 1;
SELECT @name = Name 
FROM inserted
WHILE (@counter <= @numberOfRows)
BEGIN
    WITH Q
    AS
    (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER()
    OVER (ORDER BY Name) 'Row', Name
    FROM myTbl WHERE ParentID IN
            (
                SELECT ParentID
                FROM inserted
            )
    )
    SELECT @names = Name
    FROM Q 
    WHERE Row = @counter
    IF @name = @names
    SET @result=1;
    SET @counter = @counter + 1
END
IF @result = 1
ROLLBACK TRAN
```

Comment: `inserted` and `deleted` are tables so that they can represent the results of set operations.  Designing a trigger on the assumption that they will always contain exactly one row is generally a bad plan.  That said, you should be able to use `NOT EXISTS` to filter out the rows that are in `inserted` from those you are checking.

Comment: Yeah I get that , But in this scenario I'd make sure that never more than one row would be inserted. But the problem is why the inserted row is already in myTbl too ? or am I missing something!?

Comment: If you are absolutely certain that the number of rows will never exceed one then add an explicit check and use `RaIsError` to indicate clearly that an illegal statement has been attempted.  `myTbl` looks like it has already been updated from within the trigger.  `select distinct Name from myTbl where Id not in ( select Id from inserted )`, as an example, will return all of the distinct names without considering the inserted row.

Comment: @HABO - Thnks HABO I soleved my problem using subquery that u've suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I am missing something you are making this way too hard.

Why don't you use a unique constraint on the two columns?

[table_constraint (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188066.aspx)

Comment: This One was a lot easier than using Triggers thnks. This Solved my problem too .